# Setting up expires headers with Apache with Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, bitnami

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I have added the following to my .htaccess, yet checking with www.gtmetrix.com or other website performance services comes back saying that I do not have expiry set on my headers. Has anyone got any ideas on what may be the problem?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

I also have the 'RewriteEngine On' specified in .htaccess, yet it is inside of the '', see below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
```

If it is the httpd.conf that needs to change, then I have also added expire code snipped at the bottom, please see my httd.conf at https://pastebin.com/Xdxxh53W

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Bitnami stacks do not use `.htaccess` for security and performance reasons. Instead, you would need to use `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htaccess.conf`. After modifying it, restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set it in `httpd.conf`.

you have to check that `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so` is uncommented, if it is not uncomment it.

you can write your code at last.

you must restart apache after updating httpd.conf by following command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Thank you